# How to get text from every row in a listview? (List of strings)

Tags: android, listview

I have created a ListView. In each row there is a TextView and a ToggleButton. The text showed in each TextView is a result from my Database. How can I get the text from every row in OnClick of the row's ToggleButton? Thank you!

Here is my activity code:

```
public class BuscarUsuaris extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener {
ToggleButton boto_agregar;
TextView nom_usuari;
public boolean pressed = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buscar_usuaris);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        nom_usuari=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nom_usuari);
        boto_agregar=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.boto_agregar); 


    }
    private void connect(String busqueda) {
      String data=null;

      final List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();

      ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, R.id.nom_usuari,r);

      ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      boto_agregar=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.boto_agregar);



      List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parametres.add(new BasicNameValuePair("busqueda", busqueda));
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("MY_HOST");
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametres));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("DADES OBTINGUDES", data);

            try {

       JSONArray json=new JSONArray(data);

       for(int i=0;i<json.length(); i++)
       {
        JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);
        String nombre=obj.getString("nombre");

        Log.e("PERSONA TROBADA:", nombre);

        r.add(nombre);


        list.setAdapter(adapter);

       }

      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }


    }
```

My row layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nom_usuari"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/boto_agregar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:background="@drawable/togglebutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use a custom array adapter. also toogle button does not belong to `buscar_usuaris.xml` and your app should crash if you use   `boto_agrega` coz its not initialized properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the getView of your adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0 , r){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // View from recycle
                View row = convertView;

                // Handle inflation and make sure not to re-use a header view
                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                }

                String rowText = r.get(position);

                ToggleButton tBtn = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.boto_agregar);
                tBtn.setTag(position);
                tBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        //see which row was changed
                        int position = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString());
                        //get the row text
                        String changedRowText = r.get(position);
                    }
                });

                TextView rowTV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nom_usuari);
                rowTV.setText(rowText);

                return row;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add an onClick listener.
if you have an custom adapter class, try this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> implements
        OnClickListener{
//adapter behavior

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView idView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.TextId);
        //etc..


    }
}
```